# SQL: Counting rows resulting from a join

Tags: sql, join, count

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have the following query. I essentially trying to return two columns, the Employee's name and a count of the total number of calls they have made for the current month. I have gotten the query to run, but when it does it is taking quite a while and it returns huge incorrect numbers for the count of total calls.  Can anyone give me a hand with this?

```
Select A.Name, count(1) As TotalCalls
From Calls B INNER JOIN Employees A on B.EmployeeID = A.TechID
Where A.Name IN ('Steven', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jason', 'Tom') 
AND Month(B.CreationDate) = Month(GetDate()) and Year(B.CreationDate) = Year(GetDate())
Group By A.Name
```

Edit:
I have tried the following query and I think I am pretty close now.  It is returning a result set that is accurate, I'm just not sure how to make this query only look at the current month.

```
Select A.Name, B.CallCount                                  
From Employees A Inner Join (Select EmployeeID, Count(*) As CallCount From Calls Group By EmployeeID) B
On A.TechID = B.EmployeeID
Where A.Name IN ('Steven', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jason', 'Tom') 
Group By A.Name, B.CallCount
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the query without the group by to see if it return the expected rows?

Comment: Yes, it says that "Column 'A.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Sorry copied and pasted the wrong thing, I have edited my previous comment.

Comment: What if you take away the count(1) and the group by? That's gotta work. Does it return the expect results?

Comment: If I take away the group by and count it just lists the repeats of the names of the tech's in question.  I tried counting the unique id for the calls table, but it gave me the following error.  "The count aggregate operation cannot take a uniqueidentifier data type as an argument."

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Select A.Name, count(A.name) As TotalCalls
From Calls B INNER JOIN Employees A on B.EmployeeID = A.TechID
Where A.Name IN ('Steven', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jason', 'Tom') 
AND Month(B.CreationDate) = Month(GetDate()) and Year(B.CreationDate) = Year(GetDate())
Group By A.Name
Order by TotalCalls
```

Comment: I appreciate the work, and that query does return a result set for each tech.  The problem is that the numbers returned for TotalCalls are way too big, in the hundreds of thousands, and I know that isn't right.  It seems like it is counting every possible combination from the join or something like that...

Comment: Well, try to narrow it down then. Try to get Steven's calls, for instance, for a particular month and see if it checks out. If it does, what about the rest of the months?

Comment: Here, use http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Give me a set of data i can work with, see if I can help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Thanks a lot to Hal and everyone else who commented.

```
Select A.Name, B.CallCount                                  
From Employees A Inner Join (Select EmployeeID, Count(*) As CallCount From Calls Where Month(EntryDate) = Month(GetDate()) and Year(EntryDate) = Year(GetDate()) Group By EmployeeID) B
On A.TechID = B.EmployeeID
Where A.Name IN ('Steven', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jason', 'Tom') 
Group By A.Name, B.CallCount
```